# In redux-observable, how can I measure the epics duration time when running complete?

Tags: redux-observable

In the majority situation, epics listen an action and emit an action, many async task in it. I want to measure the duration of epics between the action in and action out. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the time between tasks using `Performance.now()`:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

In the context of your actions and epics, you could include the timestamp in the initial action and then later call `Performance.now()`, subtracting the first measurement from the second. That's your delta between.

As an example, this measures from before an ajax request to after the ajax response comes back and the new action is created:

```
action$.pipe(
  ofType("PING"),
  switchMap(action => {
    const before = Performance.now();

    return ajax.getJSON("/ping").pipe(
      map(pong => {
        const after = Performance.now();
        return { type: "PONG", delta: after - before };
      })
    );
  })
);
```

Comment: no, I want to measure epics running duration in redux-observable,I think it may be need to use some rxjs operators

Comment: epics are async stream

Comment: right, and the actions you pass through can have additional properties and you can make the stream include timing information. I'll update with a little bit more