# How can I measure the duration between 2 actions using redux-observable epic?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to measure the duration of 2 actions using redux-observable epic.

There is an answer related but it doesn't really help in my situation.
[In redux-observable, how can I measure the epics duration time when running complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183011/in-redux-observable-how-can-i-measure-the-epics-duration-time-when-running-comp)

```
testeeEpic = action$ => action$.ofType('TEST_START', 'TEST_EMD')
  .pipe(
    // How to measure duration between 'TEST_START' and 'TEST_EMD'
  )

/*
`TEST_START` can be dispatched multiple times before `TEST_EMD`, 
duration between the lastest `TEST_START` and `TEST_EMD` is needed.
*/
```

It would be grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`timeInterval`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/timeInterval/) -- it measures time between two emissions.

To measure time between first `START` and next `END`:

```js
.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  timeInterval(),
  filter(({ value }) => value !== START_EVENT),
  map(({ interval }) => interval)
)
```

[Timespan between first START and next END example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/0d3433958199e441528863a9cabbbf44).

**UPDATE**

To measure time between latest `START` and following `END`:

```js
.pipe(
  timeInterval(),
  pairwise(),
  filter(([first, second]) =>
    first.value === START_EVENT
    && second.value === END_EVENT
  ),
  map(([, second]) => second.interval)
)
```

[Timespan between latest START and following END example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/73877d92ddc6ca8e4a53af1e8effb688).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Could you give a working example? :)

Comment: @LinShen updated with an example. `distinctUntilChanged ` to ignore multiple starts, `filter` to output only start-end sequences

Comment: It seems very smart. But would it be possible to measure duration between the lastest START_EVENT (the yellow one) and the END_EVENT (the green one)?

Comment: @LinShen, there you go

Comment: Your example works great! I've also found out that, in your first example, if we exchange the order of  "distinctUntilChanged()"  and "timeInterval()", it can count the duration from the latest START too.

Comment: @LinShen keep experimenting! Also, be sure to test the code you'll use against more events

Comment: For sure. Thank you very much!